# Git from behind a proxy - clone works - fetch/pull does not

Tags: git

I am using ubuntu behind a socks5 proxy and trying to use the git protocol (as opposed to http which does work). I can get git clone working by compiling [connect.c](http://bent.latency.net/bent/git/goto-san-connect-1.85/src/connect.html)

And by adding this to my ~/.ssh/config:

```
ProxyCommand connect -S socks-mydomain.co.uk %h %p
```

I have cloned a repo and have all the code, however now I am trying to merge in the changes from another repo. I have added it as a remote and now I get an error when doing this:

```
git fetch upstream

github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
```

As git clone works it seems strange that a fetch does not.
Any idea why?

Comment: This is indeed strange; git just calls `ssh` for both case. Maybe try setting the environment variable "GIT_TRACE=1" to see which command fails and how the calls differ for fetch and clone

Comment: export GIT_TRACE=1
git fetch upstream
trace: built-in: git 'fetch' 'upstream'
github.com[0: 207.97.227.239]: errno=Connection timed out
fatal: unable to connect a socket (Connection timed out)
 - not that much different!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If adding the ProxyCommand helped for your initial clone, you cloned via ssh. For the remote you just added, you use the git protocol (i.e. a git://-url). For this protocol, git does not use ssh, but some builtin network support.

Proxy support for the git protocol can be configured with the core.gitProxy variable in the [git config file](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) or the GIT_PROXY_COMMAND environment variable.

Comment: For the initial clone I used git@github.com:dereke/feature-girl.git and for the remote I used git://github.com/daniel-cloudspace/feature-girl.git - is this what you mean? I take it there is some other way to configure git to use this protocol then?

Comment: Yes. The first is another form for `ssh://git@github.com/dereke/feature-girl.git`. Whether you can also use the ssh protocol to access the other repository depends on github. It seems to me that they allow only git:// or http:// protocols for repositories where you do not have write access.

Comment: ok great, so how do you configure this protocol to get around the proxy then?

Comment: Thanks! I configured that by setting GIT_PROXY_COMMAND to be gitproxy which is a file in bin containing the following: #!/bin/sh
connect -S socks-mydomain.co.uk:1080 $*

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the Smart HTTP protocol? That just goes over port 80 or 443 so if those aren't restricted should just work.

Comment: Actually yeah, that does work. But I am curious as to why a clone would work but not a fetch. So I will leave this open for a while..

Comment: Does fetching over HTTP work? Or doesn't it work for the Git protocol?

Comment: yeah fetching over http works - it doesn't for the git protocol. however clone over git protocol does work. sorry just realised I wasn't clear about that!